# Google Sheets 2 Google Calendar - Unable to apply previously posted fixes for duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a sheet that can export entries to Google Calendar. I have done this! Unfortunately, each time I run the code it duplicates every single entry in the calendar.

I have read through the other threads that manage this issue, but I am a novice and my code is very different from the others. I also am unsure how to create a "unique ID" that can be used to manage the duplicates by checking for entries by ID.

I wonder if someone can help by reviewing my code and sheet? I have removed my calendar ID, so you will need to add your own to test the code/sheet.

```
/**
 * Import events from Google Calendar into Google Sheets
 */

function getEvents() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("[INSERT CAL ID HERE]");
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("7/1/2022 12:00 AM"), new Date("7/31/2022 11:59 PM")); //array of events - uses square brackets


var lr = ss.getLastRow(); // clean up spreadsheet - clear content when events are removed from the calendar
ss.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 5).clearContent(); // first row of data, first column of data, lr-1, number of columns of data 
//Error when blank - must have at least one row of text. Row 2 cannot be blank on first run.


for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){ //loop through all of the events to find how many things are in the array and run the function for all of them 

  var name = events[i].getTitle(); //first event i=0 - this will run through entries in the timeframe specified and get all titles
  var st = events[i].getStartTime();
  var et = events[i].getEndTime();
  var loc = events[i].getLocation();
  var des = events[i].getDescription();

  ss.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(name); //assign the variable to a column/location in the sheet. Change the number on each line to change to assign to a new column
  ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(st);
  ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"); //set date formatting for st
  ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setValue(et);
  ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"); //set date formatting for et
  ss.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(loc);
  ss.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue(des);
  
  }

}

/**
 * Export event entries from Google Sheets to the Google Calendar
 */

function addEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("[INSERT CAL ID HERE]");

  var data = ss.getRange("A2:E" + lr).getValues(); //concatentation

  for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){ 
    
    //Logger.log(data[i]); 
    // [i] moves each entry to a new line, [0] selects only the column specified

      cal.createEvent(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], {location: data[i][3], description: data[i][4]});

  }

}

/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item for invoking function addEvents()
 */

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Calendar Sync')
    .addItem('Sync now', 'addEvents')
    .addToUi();

}
```

Here is a snip of the sheet:

[Google Sheet Sample to Export to Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdPTY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent any duplicates, save the id of the event by

```
let id = cal.createEvent(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], {location: data[i][3], description: data[i][4]}).getId()
```

and save in column F for instance (if F is free)

```
ss.getRange(i+2, 6).setValue(id)
```

So expand data as follows

```
var data = ss.getRange("A2:F" + lr).getValues();
```

and when you loop `for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++)`, check `if (data[i][5] == '')`

Comment: So, I apologize but I am really new to this. How would I incorporate these bits of code into my larger code? I am unsure where they fit into the provided code in a way that works. Column F is free.

Comment: I attempted to add in the code you suggested and now the entire code has stopped working and I am getting multiple errors.

Comment: If you can give me a copy of your spreadsheet (a minimal reproducible example with blank as email), I will be pleased to send back the correct script.

Comment: Take a copy for you https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1su2yCGahKvYaG66s3jXd9pDTa96VJmiV1ZPjUQ6h-gI/copy I put timezone = Toronto. Column F will prevent you from duplicates

Comment: Does this work? Can you use this link and then make a copy? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PhmwTtAviucRDNOWi1Hst5mYiK5UFMLqkZWCLh5XU8E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I copied your file and I have tested it with my calendar, no duplicates!!!!!! You are amazing lol. I now will need to integrate this into my larger project, but thank you so much for your help with this.

Comment: Hello Mike! I hope you will see this comment if you are still out there.  I have used your code, and it works great, but, it seems that if there are too many events to show in the day and the "# more" is created on the Google Calendar, we cannot see them. When you usually click the "# more" on the day, it will open a box and show you the remaining events. With this sync set up, it instead gives the messages that "No events are scheduled for this day," yet we can those that fit. So strange, any ideas?

Comment: Hi Tanya, i am Mike's daughter and i did not want you to think that my father stopped answering. Unfortuntaley my father passed away a week or so ago and I myself do not have his skilles to answer your question. br

Comment: I am very sorry to hear about your loss. Sorry I did not check this until now and see your message. I wish you all the best.